# String concatenation without strcat in C

Tags: c, string

I am having trouble concatenating strings in C, without strcat library function. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *a1=(char*)malloc(100);
  strcpy(a1,"Vivek");
  char *b1=(char*)malloc(100);
  strcpy(b1,"Ratnavel");
  int i;
  int len=strlen(a1);

  for(i=0;i<strlen(b1);i++)
  {
     a1[i+len]=b1[i];
  }

  a1[i+len]='\0';                
  printf("\n\n A: %s",a1);

  return 0;
}
```

I made corrections to the code. This is working. Now can I do it without strcpy?

Comment: @kotlinkski, because it's homework, I'm guessing

Comment: No I just wanted to know, How to concatenate two strings without using any library functions. May be Paul was right. I am preparing for a test.

Comment: @pmg: Sorry. Am not very good at programming. I thought the array index starts from 0 and length - 1 will fit array.

Comment: @pmg: you shouldn't down vote the question just because there is a mistake in the code.

Comment: I know ... I meant that as a **VERY STRONG** attention caller. I was hoping Vivek would edit the post at the relevant places and then I'd remove the down-post and comment.

Comment: Chris Lutz makes some good criticisms in his answer, and I want to emphasize a point he makes in passing.  Do not use strlen() in the loop condition; it is a potentially expensive call and is totally unnecessary to keep calling it since the string you are computing the length of is not changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old answer below

---

You can initialize a string with `strcpy`, like in your code, or directly when declaring the char array.

```
char a1[100] = "Vivek";
```

Other than that, you can do it char-by-char

```
a1[0] = 'V';
a1[1] = 'i';
// ...
a1[4] = 'k';
a1[5] = '\0';
```

Or you can write a few lines of code that replace `strcpy` and make them a function or use directly in your main function.

---

*Old answer*

You have

```
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
    a1 [V|i|v|e|k|0|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_]
    b1 [R|a|t|n|a|v|e|l|0|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_]
```

and you want

```
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
    a1 [V|i|v|e|k|R|a|t|n|a|v|e|l|0|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_]
```

so ...

```
a1[5] = 'R';
a1[6] = 'a';
// ...
a1[12] = 'l';
a1[13] = '\0';
```

but with loops and stuff, right? :D

Try this (remember to add missing bits)

```
for (aindex = 5; aindex < 14; aindex++) {
    a1[aindex] = b1[aindex - 5];
}
```

Now think about the `5` and `14` in the loop above.

What can you replace them with? When you answer this, you have solved the programming problem you have :)

Comment: Well. I think 5 is strlen(a) and 14 is strlen(a)+strlen(b). But I did the same logic in my code and I get a segmentation fault. How do I solve it?

Comment: Your code does not have `a1` and `b1` with the extra space at the end. You allocate space for 100 characters, but then ignore that and make a1 point to a character literal (unmodifiable) without extra space (the `a1 = "Vivek";`).

Comment: But How can I do that for a char* with allocated memory?

Comment: @Vivek: char-by-char or by using a `strcpy` replacement.

Answer (score 4):

```
 char a1[] = "Vivek";
```

Will create a char array `a1` of size `6`. You are trying to stuff it with more characters than it can hold.

If you want to be able to accommodate concatenation `"Vivek"` and `"Ratnavel"` you need to have a char array of size atleast `14 (5 + 8 + 1)`.

In your **modified**  program you are doing:

```
char *a1=(char*)malloc(100);  // 1
a1 = "Vivek";                 // 2
```

1: Will allocate a memory chunk of size 100 bytes, makes `a1` point to it.
2: Will make `a1` point to the string literal `"Vivek"`. This string literal cannot be modified.

To fix this use strcpy to copy the string into the allocated memory:

```
char *a1=(char*)malloc(100);  
strcpy(a1,"Vivek");
```

Also the `for` loop condition `i<strlen(b1)-1` will not copy last character from the string, change it to `i<strlen(b1)`

And

```
a1[i]='\0';
```

should be

```
a1[i + len]='\0';
```

as the new length of `a1` is `i+len` and you need to have the NUL character at that index.

And don't forget to `free` your dynamically allocated memory once you are done using it.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. But can we eliminate the use of strcpy() too. Can we do it some other way so that our code will not have any library functions. I  edited my code. Pls check. Thanks for ur reply. +1

Comment: `malloc` and `strcpy` is really an overshoot: `a1[100] = "Vivek";` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot safely write into those arrays, since you have not made sure that enough space is available. If you use `malloc()` to allocate space, you can't then overwrite the pointer by assigning to string literal. You need to use `strcpy()` to copy a string into the newly allocated buffers, in that case.

Also, the length of a string in C is computed by the `strlen()` function, not `length()` that you're using.

When concatenating, you need to terminate at the proper location, which your code doesn't seem to be doing.

Here's how I would re-implement `strcat()`, if needed for some reason:

```
char * my_strcat(char *out, const char *in)
{
  char *anchor = out;
  size_t olen;

  if(out == NULL || in == NULL)
    return NULL;

  olen = strlen(out);
  out += olen;
  while(*out++ = *in++)
    ;
  return anchor;
}
```

Note that this is just as bad as `strcat()` when it comes to buffer overruns, since it doesn't support limiting the space used in the output, it just assumes that there is enough space available.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. `length` isn't a function. `strlen` is, but you probably shouldn't call it in a loop - `b1`'s length won't change on us, will it? Also, it returns a `size_t`, which may be the same size as `int` on your platform but will be unsigned. This can (but usually won't) cause errors, but you should do it right anyway.
2. `a1` only has enough space for the first string, because the compiler doesn't know to allocate extra stack space for the rest of the string since. If you provide an explicit size, like `[100]`, that should be enough for your purposes. If you need robust code that doesn't make assumptions about what is "enough", you should look into `malloc` and friends, though that may be a lesson for another day.
3. Your loop stops too early. `i < b1_len` (assuming you have a variable, `b1_len`, that was set to the length of `b1` before the loop began) would be sufficient - `strlen` doesn't count the `'\0'` at the end.
4. But speaking of counting the `'\0'` at the end, a slightly more efficient implementation could use `sizeof a1 - 1` instead of `strlen(a1)` in this case, since `a1` (and `b1`) are declared as arrays, not pointers. It's your choice, but remember that `sizeof` won't work for pointers, so don't get them mixed up.
   EDIT: New problems:
5. `char *p = malloc(/*some*/); p = /* something */` is a problem. `=` with pointers doesn't copy contents, it copies the value, so you're throwing away the old pointer value you got from `malloc`. To copy the contents of a string into a `char *` (or a `char []` for that matter) you'd need to use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, or (my preference) `memcpy`. (Or just a loop, but that's rather silly. Then again, it may be good practice if you're writing your own `strcat`.)
6. Unless you're using C++, I wouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`, but that's a religious war and we don't need one of those.
7. If you have `strdup`, use it. If you don't, here is a working implementation:

   ```
   char *strdup(const char *c)
   {
       size_t l = strlen(c);
       char *d = malloc(l + 1);
       if(d) memcpy(d, c, l + 1);
       return d;
   }
   ```

   It is one of the most useful functions not in the C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using strcpy() too ;)

```
char *a = (char *) malloc(100);
char *b = (char *) malloc(100);

strcpy(a, "abc");               // initializes a
strcpy(b, "def");               // and b

strcpy((a + strlen(a)), b);     // copy b at end of a

printf("%s\n",a);               // will produce: "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is an easy one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int xstrlen(char *);
void xstrcat(char *,char *,int);
void main()
{
    char source[]="Sarker";
    char target[30]="Maruf";
    int j=xstrlen(target);
    xstrcat(target,source,j);
    printf("Source String: %s\nTarget String: %s",source,target);
}
int xstrlen(char *s)
{
    int len=0;
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        len++;
        s++;
    }
    return len;
}
void xstrcat(char *t,char *s,int j)
{
    while(*t!='\0')
    {
        *t=*t;
        t++;
    }
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        *t=*s;
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to factor out your `strcat` logic to a separate function. If you make use of pointer arithmetic, you don't need the `strlen` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* To completely get rid of this, 
                       implement your our strcpy as well */

static void 
my_strcat (char* dest, char* src)
{
  while (*dest) ++dest;
  while (*src) *(dest++) = *(src++);
  *dest = 0;
}

int 
main()
{
  char* a1 = malloc(100);
  char* b1 = malloc(100);

  strcpy (a1, "Vivek");  
  strcpy (b1, " Ratnavel");

  my_strcat (a1, b1);
  printf ("%s\n", a1); /* => Vivek Ratnavel */

  free (a1);
  free (b1);
  return 0;
}
```