# String Concatenation function in C doesn;t do anything, so what is the correct way?

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm learning C language...

I want to write a function that concatenates two strings.
I wrote a function but it doesn't work;
it doesn't give any error in compilation,
but while running it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
char* str_sum(char* s1, char* s2){
    int j = strlen(s1);
    int i=0;
    while(s2[i]){
            s1[j]=s2[i];
            j++;
            i++;
    }
    return s1;
}
int main(){
    char* s1, s2;
    s1 = "Joe";
    s2 = "Black";
    printf("%s\n",sum_str(s1,s2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you didn't write a function that concatenates two strings. You wrote a function that overflows a buffer that you can't modify in the first place because it's a string literal (read-only)

Comment: so can u tell me how to modify my str_sum function code?

Comment: Hint 1: Allocate memory to hold the entire string. Hint 2: strcat.

Comment: @namco - Yes: possible duplicate of [String concatenation without strcat in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438541/string-concatenation-without-strcat-in-c)

Comment: You can start with baby steps, i) take "Joe" and "Black" in two arrays. ii)Then copy them in a third array(it should have enough space) iterating "Joe" and "Black" and return that third array. Once you do this you will be having enough idea hoe to handle through pointers.

Comment: Hint 3: run it in a debugger to understand the first comment (also, if learning the C language, get a better text, something like K&R)

Comment: very bad... you know, i dont want use any functions like strcat or etc. and this is why i tried to code like this. is there any way to solve this problem in this way???

Comment: Also, the declaration `char* s1,s2;` is probably not what you want; it is equivalent to `char* s1; char s2;`.

Comment: And you have also defined function `str_sum` but call function `sum_str`.

Comment: Time to buy _and read_ that peer-reviewed C book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function could look like this:

```
char* sum_str(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int lenS1 = strlen(s1);
    int lenS2 = strlen(s2);
    char* newString = malloc((lenS1 + lenS2 + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    while(i < lenS1)
    {
        newString[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(i < lenS2 + lenS1)
    {
        newString[i] = s2[i - lenS1];
        i++;
    }
    newString[i] = '\0';
    return newString;
}
```

Note that this function allocates new string which means you should `free` this data when you finish with this string. Also note that terminating character (`'\0'`) is stored at the end of this char array so that `printf` can "print" it properly.

Here's main:

```
int main()
{
  char *s1, *s2, *s3;
  s1 = "Joe";
  s2 = " Black";
  s3 = sum_str(s1,s2);
  printf("%s\n", s3);
  free(s3);
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `Joe Black`

Note that I have declared variables `s1`, `s2` and `s3` like this: `char *s1, *s2, *s3;`. If I write it like this: `char *s1, s2, s3;` then variables `s2` and `s3` are no longer arrays of characters but only characters.

Also note that this program:

```
  char *s1 = "Joe";
  s1[0] = 'X';
  printf("%s\n", s1);
```

will crash since it tries to change constant string literal `"Joe"`. `s1` is pointer to first character of this literal in this case.

But this program will work fine and its output will be `Xoe`:

```
  char s1[] = "Joe";
  s1[0] = 'X';
  printf("%s\n", s1);
```

`s1` is an array initialized with string `"Joe"` so it's OK to change it.

Comment: That whole "Don't forget to free it" part is why `strcat` makes you pass in the dest buffer (and why `strncat` is better) ;)

Comment: He is learning basics in C, that's why I wrote this function to copy character by character so that it helps to understand how strings work in C.

Comment: @LihO in your code instead of "char *" return type , can i wrote "string" as return type? keeping rest of the code same as it is?

Comment: @Priyanka: In case you want to use `std::string` objects you could simply do: `std::string newStr = str1 + str2;` (if `str1` and `str2` are `std::string`s as well)

Comment: @LihO m not talking abt about newstr, m talking about the return type of function "sumStr()" , can i replace char* with "string"??

Comment: @Priyanka: Yes, but this function was intended to be used in C, there could be no pointers (neither `malloc` call) at all in C++ approach.

Comment: @Priyanka: The `std::string` object will be built from `char*` automatically: http://ideone.com/jX0DQz

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
char* str_sum(char* s1, char* s2){
   int len = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);
   char* buff = malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);

   strcpy(buff, s1); //we don't need the zero termination char here.
   strcpy(buff + strlen(s1), s2);
   buff[len] = '\0';
   return buff;
}
```

Comment: You can't do `char buff[len]` in C, because it should be sized at compilation time.

Comment: `strcpy(buff, s1-1);` starts copying from 1 location prior to where `s1` starts

Comment: @sinsedrix - that's not entirely true. `c99` does allow this, and modern versions of gcc allow it by default (probably because as an extension of `c90`)

Comment: Also shoulnd't cast the return of `malloc`. And you know `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. Would be good to check if `malloc` did not fail too.

Comment: And also it would be very good to set the last element of the buff[] to 0

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues with the code:

1. string s1 could be pointing to read-only memory and can not be
   modified.  Running your example on my machine cause a Segmentation Fault.
2. string s1 is not large enough to hold the additional
   contents of s2. It should be declared as:
   char s1[30] = "Joe";

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't allocate memory to write your new string. Maybe youcould use `strcat` or rewrite it like this:

```
char* str_sum(char* s1, char* s2) {
  int l1 = strlen(s1), l2 = strlen(s2), i;
  char sum = (char *)malloc(l1+l2+1);

  for(i=0; i<l1; i++) sum[i] = s1[i];
  for(i=0; i<l2; i++) sum[i+l1] = s2[i];

  sum[l1+l2] = '\0'; // NULL terminated    
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Where goes the NULL terminator?

Comment: The concatenated result string is not NULL terminated

Answer (score 0):

Your `str_sum` function needs to create an array that is large enough to hold the contents of the concatenated strings.

```
char *str_sum( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
  char *ret = malloc( strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1 ); // 1 for terminating NULL char

  if( ret == NULL ) {
    return NULL;
  }
  strcpy( ret, s1 );
  strcpy( &ret[strlen(s1)], s2 );
  return ret;
}
```

Also, the caller will need to `free()` the returned pointer (if it is not NULL).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either with strcat()
or without (which is kind of meaningless but I include it for completeness sake. Refer to the example below.

```
char* str_sum_wstrcat(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int len1 = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    int i=0;
    char* sum = malloc(len1+len2+1);
    strcpy(sum,s1);
    strcat(sum,s2);


    return sum;
}

char* str_sum(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int len1 = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    int i=0;
    char* sum = malloc(len1+len2+1);
    strcpy(sum,s1);
    while(i<len2)
    {
        sum[len1+i] = s2[i];
        i++;
    }
    sum[len1+i]='\0';


    return sum;
}

int main()
{
  char* s1 = malloc(100);
  char* s2 = malloc(100);
  s1 = "Joe";
  s2 = "Black";
  printf("%s\n",str_sum(s1,s2));
  //or
  printf("%s\n",str_sum_wstrcat(s1,s2)); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing will cause a segmentation fault. The string literals probably lie in the read only section of the memory. Its a run time error if you try to write to such a location. Use `malloc` instead as the other answers say. Its a mistake many beginners including myself make.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without any predefined functions. The result of the concatenation is put into the third parameter of the function which is the result string:

```
  void str_cat_101(char const input1[], char const input2[], char result[])
  {
     int i, z;
     for(i = 0; input1[i] != 0; i++)
     {
        result[i] = input1[i];
     }
     for(z=0; input2[z] != 0; z++)
     {
        result[i+z] = input2[z];
     }
     result[i+z] = 0;
  }
```