# How to copy a character array into another character array in 'c' using pointers and without using string library

Tags: c

How do I copy a character array into another character array in `C` using pointers and without using string library?

I've tried this:

Header File:

```
char strconcat(char a[100], char b[100]) {
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(a[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
    }
    while(b[j] != '\0'){
        a[i] = b[j];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    return a[100];
}
```

Comment: that's lovely code... enjoy what happens to your system if `a` happens to already have 100 chars worth of text in it before you start the copy operation, or doesn't have a null terminator.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438541/string-concatenation-without-strcat-in-c

Comment: @MarcB in C, functions aren't supposed to be safe. They are supposed to be called properly. For example a double free() will make you crash.

Comment: @MarcB: This doesn't put null-byte-terminattor but it is very close to C's `strcat()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 char *strconcat(char *dst, const char *src)
 {
     char *bak = dst;
     while (*dst) dst++;
     while (*dst = *src)
     {
          dst++;
          src++;
     }
     return bak;
 }
```

Note you cannot have `char a[100]` as your function parameters. In C this notation is automatically converted to `char a[]` that is equivalent to `char *a`.

You also don't have to compare things to 0. Omitting a comparison will make that happen by default.

Comment: @user3121023 `*src` being NUL. The value of an assignment expression is the value being assigned.

Comment: It is not comparing `*src` to `*dst`. It is setting the value of `*dst` to `*src` and the loop will stop if that happened to be the null-terminator `\0`.

Comment: Could u explain what u did in the while statements if possible

Comment: `dst` and `src` are pointers to arrays. `dst` points to `dst[0]`, and `*dst` IS `dst[0]` (get value of pointer). When I do `dst++` I walk the array, and it now points to `dst[1]`, and `*dst` is `dst[1]`. So basically I'm doing the same as you but I'm walking the arrays without using `i/j` indexes.

Comment: I can see how the "while (*dst = *src)" can be confusing to some who have less experience.  Having said that, this is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
void strconcat(char *a, char *b)
{

 int i=0,j=0;
 while(a[i++]!='\0')
         ;
 while(b[j]!='\0')
       a[i++]=b[j++];
 a[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first version naively assumes enough space in destination,

```
char *
my_strcat(char *destp, char *srcp)
{
    if(!destp) return(destp); //check that dest is valid
    if(!srcp) return(destp);  //check that src is valid
    char *dp=destp; //save original destp
    while(*dp) { dp++; }      //find end of destp
    while(*srcp)
    {
        *dp++ = *srcp++;      //copy src to dest, then increment
    }
    return(destp);
}
```

The second version allows you to specify maximum size for destination,

```
char *
my_strncat(char *destp, char *srcp, long max)
{
    if(!destp) return(destp); //check that dest is valid
    if(!srcp) return(destp);  //check that src is valid
    char *dp=destp; //save original destp
    long x=0;
    while(*dp && (x<max)) { dp++; ++x; }      //find end of destp
    while(*srcp && (x<max))   //copy from src while more space in dst
    {
        *dp++ = *srcp++; ++x; //copy src to dest, then increment
    }
    *dp = '\0'; //ensure destination null terminated
    return(destp);
}
```

Comment: `*dp++ = *srcp++;` <<< the C standard guarantees that this will be doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Havenard: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `*(dp++) = *(srcp++)` and `(*dp)++ = (*srcp)++` will have completely different behaviours. The absence of parenthesis leaves it open for interpretation unless something guarantees the order of those parameters.

Comment: @Havenard: This is defined to do the former of your examples (the latter wouldn't compile, `(*dp)++` isn't an lvalue), postfix binds stronger than everything else (including (prefix) unary).

Comment: Please refer to precedence of * vs ++.